# How to perform redirection to Aspx page present in DLL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a .dll in which I have added an aspx file in the views folder (present under root directory). I want to call the method present in the dll file class and want to redirect data to that particular aspx page. Here is my basic implementation in dll:

```
public void redirect(Dictionary<string, object> obj){
            try{
                    Console.WriteLine("data received"+obj);
                    string encryptedValue = obj["data"].ToString();
                    string endpoint = obj["endpoint"].ToString();
                    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedValue)){
                        Console.WriteLine("Redirecting for Payment to : "+endpoint);
                        RedirectionProperty property = new RedirectionProperty(endpoint,encryptedValue);
                        Console.WriteLine(property.Url);
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("url",property.Url);
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("data",property.PaymentData);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("hello");
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/views/Redirect.aspx",false);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error performing Redirection ");
                }
        }
```

Is it possible to perform redirection to an aspx page present in the dll file?

Comment: An aspx page inside a dll? Why? And a Views folder indicates move of an MVC enviroment to me.

Comment: The DLL project is not a MVC one. It's a simple console application. I have created a folder with a "views" name. I can rename it anyway. I want to call a method present in a cs file in DLL and want to redirect to asp page.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for, is to reference aspx pages in a separate library. [Take a look at this guide here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Oct/18/Packaging-ASPNET-ASPX-Pages-into-a-separate-Assembly) which basically describes the following:

1. Created a new Web Application Project (I suppose a regular project would also work)
2. Added a new page to it
3. Compiled the project made sure it works and runs
4. Created a Web Deployment Project for the WAP project
5. Set options for a single Merge assembly, and not updateable
6. Add a Post build step to copy the two DLLs for the project to the Bin directory of the main project
7. Creat an HTTP handler to invoke the compiled Page